# Devise on Rails: cannot access after having migrated database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, devise, database-migration, pg-dump

I've restored locally an old application. Everything seems to work, but Devise doesn't allow me to access using the existing user/password. The only way is to create a new user/password. Anyway on the production server the old user/password works fine.

Is there anything I need to be aware of?

I've dump the production database with the following command:

```
pg_dump my_production_db --no-owner -f my-backup.sql
```

Then I've restore it locally this way:

```
psql -U my-user -d my_local_db -f my-backup.sql
```

Using Rails 5.2.1 and Postgres 10.

Comment: Might the passwords be salted with the database name, machine name, or some similar bit-of-data-that-varies-between-systems? If you create a new user of the same name and password in both systems are the password hashes the same?

Comment: You are right, it's different: `$2a$11$SQqGMi.xT8/3JYM59yEa3usqoumBjh6z9rczOTpKVkuuRBRgEXDPK`
`$2a$11$HmG6qaYtOxEY/PbyUgvy7.2DM/894ujSZsIbI7hSUfMvUVf/3kNCS`. Now what? How should I go about?

Comment: I'm not really clear what the goal is; are you trying to get it to work locally using some username and password embedded in the code? In which case you can recreate the same user and password and get the different hash locally - the details are hence the same but the stored hashes are different

Comment: See, it's weird because I've been doing this for years with Capistrano or Heroku CLI, but doing it straight with `pg_dump` seems to affect Devise password salt. My goal is to migrate the db to work locally and I'd prefer to keep the database as it is, without re-hasing users' passwords.

Comment: What command would you use to dump and restore a database from remote to local environment? Should I amend mine?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-does-devise-keep-your-passwords-safe-d367f6e816eb/ ?

Comment: Thanks. Anyway I will investigate it later, meanwhile we just recreated the credentials for each user to quickly solve the issue.

Comment: Same issue I am facing as we recently migrated all code to new server and restored database from old server, but user login is not working. Any suggestions?